# Laravel5.2, MySql, Redis, Socket.io private Chatting (need suggesstion)

Tags: mysql, node.js, redis, socket.io, laravel-5

Hi I am developing a real time chat application using Laravel 5.2 redis nodeJs It's working fine for chat room but for the private chat I would like to use 
a filtering by unique username.

```
socket.emit(receiverUniqueUserName, data); //NodeJs server side using the receiver name on socket emit.

socket.on(receiverUniqueUserName, function (data) {  //using the same receiver name at client side of socket.
```

I am not sure if it is it efficient or not? If not then could anyone suggest me the efficient way with example for laravel5.2, MySql, Redis, Socket.io private Chatting?

Chunk of codes:
From the controller I am publishing data through channel "message-channel"

```
public function sendMessage(){
        $redis = LRedis::connection();
        $data = ['message' => Request::input('message'), 'senderUniqueUserName' => Request::input('senderUniqueUserName'), 'receiverUniqueUserName' => Request::input('receiverUniqueUserName')];
        $redis->publish('message-channel', json_encode($data));
        return response()->json([$redis]);
}
```

At the server side for the nodeJs:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var redisClient = redis.createClient();
    redisClient.subscribe('message-channel');
    redisClient.on('message', function (channel, data) {
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
        var receiverUniqueUserName = jsonObj.receiverUniqueUserName;
        socket.emit(receiverUniqueUserName, data); //using the receiver name on socket emit.
    });
});
```

At the client side for socket:

```
socket.on(receiverUniqueUserName, function (data) {  //using the same receiver name at client side of socket.
    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $("#messages").append("<div><strong>" + data.senderUniqueUserName + " : </strong><span>" + data.message + "</span></div>");

});
```

Comment: Hi, in my opinion it would be better using the built-in socket.io redisStore and simply make the client send the messages (socket.io-js). no need for the php server to handle it. you can implement some auth in your node.js server.

Comment: Thank you @GuyS for replying. But there are some dependencies with Laravel at my application. So it is essential to use php. BTW can you please send me an example or tutorial link according to your suggestion, so that I can try with that?